# sql server 2008 can't use VIEW created with dynamic sql in PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

The Procedure below will run ok in SQL Server 2005, but failed in 2008 with ... `Invalid object name 'vTemp'`

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[bulksaverecord]
as
begin

if exists (select * from sysobjects where id=object_id('vTemp')) 
begin
drop view vTemp
end

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql='CREATE VIEW vTemp AS SELECT top 0 FromType,TypeID,AssessUser, 
          TypeTimeType,AssessTime,ItemRoleKey,UserName,SourceKey,  
          PartID,PartName,PositionName,ItemID,ItemName,ItemType,ItemScript,
          ItemDataSourceName,ItemField,ItemKPI,ItemFun,ItemFunLimit,ItemKill,
          AllKill,ItemMark,ItemPower,MarkScript,PowerScript,FromKey 
          FROM AssessMark'
exec sp_executesql @sql
if exists (select * from sysobjects where id=object_id('vTemp')) 
begin
    exec ('SELECT * FROM vTemp')
    SELECT * FROM vTemp -- throws the error here
end

end
```

It seems that the VIEW created with dynamic sql in PROCEDURE, will have a scope in the DYNAMIC SQL, even though the VIEW is created in fact.

Comment: If you want a temporary table why aren't you using one? Views aren't meant to be tem objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! I had found the reasons.

I change: create view to create dbo.view, the problem is gone.
So

Comment: So anybody need to notice your current sql acount's right. I meet this problem because my current sql acount is not dbo, so create view will create a view, not dbo.view. If you set your sql acount rightly, you will not see this problem. I hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This test scripts works repeatedly for me:

```
if object_id('TestProc') is not null
    drop procedure TestProc
if object_id('TestView') is not null
    drop view TestView
go
create proc TestProc
as
exec ('create view TestView as select 1 as a')
select * from TestView
go
exec TestProc
```

Like Gordon Linoff answered, double check your view definition?

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure works fine on my installation of SQL Server 2008  when I modify the view definition to be:

```
select * from information_schema.tables
```

I suspect that you have a problem with your view definition.